# Magento 2 : How to drag the unwanted attributes to the right

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute

I'm not able to drag the unwanted attributes to the right.

**=> For example :** `country_of_manufacture`.

it cannot be dragged across the line to the right where the **unassigned attributes** are.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the unwanted columns from the product grid by unchecking them from the columns sub-section.

[image: Hide Column]

Dragging the column to the right does not seem possible because the rightmost column is fixed for action column.

Please let me know if you want something else.